# jQuery Accordion working with table

Tags: jquery

I would like to use an existing table as an accordion.

This is the code I have

```
<div class="details">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Headline</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Attribute 1</td>
        <td>Option 1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Attribute 2</td>
        <td>Option 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Attribute 3</td>
        <td>Option 3</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

With click on `<thead>` the `<tbody>` should slide down and with another click the `<tbody>` should slide up.

I've tried other suggestions from SO but it doesn't work.

Comment: where you want to click? in a button a text or the same table?

Comment: I would like to click in the table header

Comment: Ok look my answer and you have a working example. If you need I can add an explanation of the process.

Comment: Awesome!!! Is it possiblt to set the default appearance only the <thead> is shown when the site loads?

Comment: Done look the answer now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you have a working example

```js
$( "thead" ).click(function() {
  $( this ).closest("table").find("tbody").slideToggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="details">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Headline</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody style="display:none">
      <tr>
        <td>Attribute 1</td>
        <td>Option 1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Attribute 2</td>
        <td>Option 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Attribute 3</td>
        <td>Option 3</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: This is what I would like to get with <thead> element.

Comment: I eddited it to work with the <thead>. It's what you need?

Answer (score 0):

Because the markup of your accordion container needs pairs of headers and content panels I changed a bit your html:

```js
$(function () {
  $('.details').accordion({
    collapsible: true,
    active: false
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="details">
    <h3>Headline</h3>
    <table>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Attribute 1</td>
            <td>Option 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Attribute 2</td>
            <td>Option 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Attribute 3</td>
            <td>Option 3</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("thead").click(function () {
            $(this).closest("table").find("tbody").slideToggle();
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>


    <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Headline</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody style="display:none">
      <tr>
        <td>Attribute 1</td>
        <td>Option 1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Attribute 2</td>
        <td>Option 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Attribute 3</td>
        <td>Option 3</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>


</body>
</html>
```